# Where f is a function, does $f ab = f(a)b~ \text{or}~ f(ab)$?

Tags: functions, notation

I know $\sin ab = \sin(ab)$, but does this apply to other functions?

Comment: Do you mean $y*f(x)=f(xy)?$

Comment: @MathNoob I think that's the whole point of the OP's question.  They are confused about when you are talking about the input of a function, and when you are talking about multiplication.  The lack of parentheses could mean different things, and they want it made clear when each scenario is implied.

Comment: GerryMyerson is quoted as saying "Wise people will stick in enough parentheses to make it impossible for anyone to mistake the meaning."  It through an abuse of notation that we sometimes write $\sin ab$, and that is unfortunate.  The official viewpoint should be that it is in poor taste to do that and it is better to be in the habit of always using parenthesis with functions including sine and cosine.

Comment: @JMoravitz Generally speaking I agree, though in the case of $\sin ab$ in particular I'd be very surprised to find any literature where this notation meant anything other than $\sin(ab)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *typically* the convention that the argument of an univariate function lacking parenthesis is the product of the factors of the term following the symbol *until* another function symbol is encountered.

$$\begin{align}
\cos a \, b + c &= \cos (ab)+c
\\
\ln a \cos b &= \ln (a) \cdot \cos (b)
\\
{\rm\,f\,}a\,b{\rm\,g\,}c &= {\rm\,f}(ab) {\rm\,g}(c)
\end{align}
$$

However, it is only typically so, and you can't always rely on an author following the convention.

The best practice is: *whenever* there may be doubt, use parenthesis to be clear about it.